# $http POST request response returning a JSON object in service, but when called in the Controller it is undefined

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

So pretty much I have a service that contains functions for making some REST method calls via the $http service in AngularJS.  These methods are then being accessed and called in the Controller.

When the method gets called via the controller the data printed to console in the service is what I expected, the JSON object.  But once that function returns it's data back to the controller it goes undefined.

I'm not too sure what the reason for this is, and would love some insight into why this is happening, does it have to do with scoping or garbage collection?

Thanks!

So here the Service 'hub'

```
  this.getAllHubs = function() {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://****.com',
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log('In hub.js ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
      this.hubs = response.data;
      return response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      // Error response right here
    }); 
  };
```

So as expected the first console output prints the object properly

And here is the Controller code

```
app.controller('HubCtrl', HubCtrl);

HubCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','hub'];

function HubCtrl($scope,hub) {
  $scope.hubs = hub.getAllHubs();
  console.log('In ctrl ' + $scope.hubs);

  $scope.addHub = function(_hub) {
    console.log('In Ctrl ' + _hub);
    hub.addHub(_hub);
  };  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not return the data from the function `this.getAllHubs`.

```
  this.getAllHubs = function() {
    return $http({              // Put a return here
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://****.com',
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log('In hub.js ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
      this.hubs = response.data;
      return response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      // Error response right here
    }); 
  };
```

And that's not enough, because the return value is actually a [$q Promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), to use the value of the promise:

```
function HubCtrl($scope,hub) {
  // getAllHubs() now returns a promise
  var hubsPromise = hub.getAllHubs();

  // We have to '.then' it to use its resolved value, note that this is asynchronous!
  hubsPromise.then(function(hubs){
    $scope.hubs = hubs;
    console.log('In ctrl ' + $scope.hubs);
  });

  $scope.addHub = function(_hub) {
    console.log('In Ctrl ' + _hub);
    hub.addHub(_hub);
  };  
}
```

Comment: That was it my friend, thank you for taking the time out to help me, I really appreciate it!  Enjoy the rest of your night/day!